# Custom ADFS claim rules

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, adfs

I am implementing SAML with a web based application and ADFS.  The authentication side of thing is working but we now need to pass extra information.  The application requires the SAML response in the following format:

```
<saml:AttributeStatement>
 <saml:Attribute Name="mailNickname">
 <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">joe.smith182</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
 <saml:Attribute Name="memberOf">
 <saml:AttributeValue>CN=SCHOOL.STUDENT.YR9,OU=Groups,OU=Portal,OU=Services,DC=ABC,DC=WIN</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
 <saml:Attribute Name="sn">
 <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Smith</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
 <saml:Attribute Name="givenName">
 <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Joe</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
 <saml:Attribute Name="mail">
 <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">joe.smith@mysite.com.au</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
 <saml:Attribute Name="borrowerType">
 <saml:AttributeValue xsi:type="xs:string">Student</saml:AttributeValue>
 </saml:Attribute>
<saml:AttributeStatement>
```

What claim rules will we need to setup in ADFS to get this information passed in this format?  In particular how can we get the memberOf attribute?  I'm not that familiar with claim rule formatting in ADFS so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your adding a rule using the claim guide its quite simple. I dont remember how the inteface looks, but when you add a claim, choose the claim rule template: Send LDAP Attributes as Claims.

Then type a name and choose memberships(or something like it) in the LDAP attribute dropdown and type memeberOf in the outgoing claim type.

Then save the rule and you shoudl be good to go

If you want to have a custom attribute name add these two rules

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", Issuer == "AD AUTHORITY"]
 => add(store = "Active Directory", types = ("memberOf"), query = ";memberOf;{0}", param = c.Value);


c:[Type == "memberOf"]
 => issue(Type = "YOUR_CUSTOM_NAME", Value = c.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Stefan.  Some of that should be straight forward but I'm not sure if there is a way to set them so that they send a custom attribute name.  The one in particular I'm not sure is the memberOf which needs to pass some details in a string from AD.  I'm not even sure if this is possible so hoping for some clues....  Thanks for your time.

Comment: Try out the claim rules I added to the answere